# C# encoding.ascii.getstring problem

Tags: c#

in the snippet given below i get error in windows application form but same code works fine for console application. Do i have to make any consideration in that aspect?

Any idea would be appreciated.

```
 Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024]; 
int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0); 
//Convert Byte to String string 
sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive);
```

This works fine in console application, but i am trying to run this code in forms based application now , but i get error that GETstring needs an argument. Could any one please show the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Please cease using Hungarian notation from now until eternity.

Comment: Are both the apps using the same framework?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no difference for this code whether you run it in a console or WinForms application. I think you must have an error elsewhere in your code.

Guessing from the error message, perhaps you wrote the following by accident:

```
sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString();
```

This gives the following error:

```
No overload for method 'GetString' takes '0' arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data is received from the socket

```
int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);
```

The 'GetString` has an overload....

```
//Convert Byte to String string 
sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive, 0, i);
```

It should be noteworthy to check if the value of `i` is greater than 1 in order to check first, otherwise the above 'GetString' method could fail if `i` is -1.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

One possibilty could be, if by any chance you are working over Forms Application based over .NET `Compact Framework` ? If so, this method is not supported. you have to use

`Encoding.GetString(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` Method.

Reference: [**Encoding.GetString Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx)